# Flutter imports don't exist after update to v0.5.1

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, updating

After recently updating flutter to `flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta`, certain imports are no longer being supported in my project.

On all of the imports, **the issue reads** : `[dart] Target of URI doesn't exist`

Could someone please correct these to current versions, or simply give me a link as to where to find updated versions for me to fix this issue myself.

**The imports are;**

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart'
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is in my `pubspec.yaml`,

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  shimmer: "^0.0.4"
  path_provider: "^0.4.1"
  url_launcher: ^3.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.0
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.1.6



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: What's in your `pubspec.yaml`? What does `flutter packages upgrade` do? Do you see any of the packages in `.packages`?

Comment: Please see my edit for the relevant contents of my pubspec.yaml, and I **can't** find the packages in .packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your imports you have the following:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

that is not in the `pubspec.yaml`

You need to add it under the `dependencies` field:

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.11.3+17
```

and then from the command line run `flutter packages get` or click "Packages Get" in the action ribbon at the top of `pubspec.yaml`.

Also if the `.packages` file is empty, then after running the above command it should add the dependencies and any of its transitive dependencies and updates the mapping in the that file.

Comment: This looks great, but can you give me the other dependency’s for the pubspec.yaml file? This looks like a great fix for the HTML dependency but I’m looking for all of the listed imports. Thanks

Comment: You already have them all listed `cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  shimmer: "^0.0.4"
  path_provider: "^0.4.1"
  url_launcher: ^3.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.0
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.1.6` only shared_preferences is not imported When you do packages get you should see them in the .packages file

Comment: This works brilliantly thanks, I just realised (and this can be found in my original question) that the only reason `path_provider` doesn't work is because I didn't end the import with a `;`. Thanks for your help.